# Gulp plugin to do a JavaScript "include"

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

Is there a Gulp plugin that allows me to include/concatenate JavaScript files together?

I'm trying to have a way in which I can "include" the contents of one JavaScript file in to others. By include, I mean having something like this:

```
// main.js
var a = 2;
///include an-include-file.import.js

// an-include-file.import.js
var b = 5;
```

"Compile" to something like this:

```
// compiled.js
var a = 2;
var b = 5;
```

Or, probably even better, something like this:

```
 // compiled.js v2
 var a = 2;

 // wrapped in an anonymous, self-calling function to isolate scope
 (function () {
     var b = 5;
 })();
```

I wrote a plugin myself to do just that, but I'd like to be able to use source maps. Implementing source maps myself is a bit more effort than I'd like to devote to this little project.

Now, I know I could use something like `gulp-concat`, but there isn't an easy way to control their order. I'd have to modify the gulpfile every time I add a new file, and manually list them all out (or have lots of complicated patterns), which is a rather large pain.

I'd prefer something where I can use an import or include to precisely control where the file goes, and control it from the scripts themselves, not the build tool. Very similar to how LESS or something does it.

For LESS, what I do is I name suffix files with ".import.less" if I don't want them to generate their own standalone file, and then `@import` them where I want them in other files. This makes it very easy to only generate the files I want, without simply creating one giant file.

Comment: use the format that everyone else uses and write your code as modules. Either ES6 or CommonJS (the kind of that Node.js uses) work just fine. Don't reinvent the wheel, just use the wheels already sold everywhere.

Comment: I'm just now looking at using Babel and just stumbled across the modules bit. Can Babel transpile to a format that can be used in a typical web browser format? I'm very familiar with CommonJS `require/modules.exports` format, but last I checked, that won't work in browsers. Also, is it possible for it to transpile them in to a single file (for performance reasons)?

Comment: no, it won't, which is why you write your code as modules, and then bundle it with a bundler. Currently "webpack" is super popular, a slightly older model is "browserify". Both take your (possibly quite many) separate commonjs modules and turn them into a single file that can load just fine in your browser (unless your modules make use of things that *can't* work in the browser). Google for "javascript build system" and read a few blog posts/articles on the various current ones, and you're off to a better start.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did end up going with WebPack+Babel+ES6-style modules. Thanks.

Comment: a chain of [`.pipe(addsrc('js/file_x.js'))`](https://github.com/urish/gulp-add-src) could do an order-preserving job? (only then followed by conact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking Mike's idea and using WebPack, in addition to Babel, to create ES6-style modules.

The basics look like this:

```
// math.js
export function sum (a, b) { return a + b; }

// main.js
import sum from "math";
console.log(sum(1, 2));
```

I use Gulp to handle my build process, which in a simplified manner looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    return gulp.src('main.js')
        .pipe(webpack())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

My actual usage is much more complex, but that's the basic idea. I have to use babel-loader (with the ES2015 preset) in my webpack config to have it process the ES6 in to ES5, then WebPack puts them together in to one file.

Related reading:

- Babel - https://babeljs.io/
- Babel ES2015 Preset - https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/
- WebPack - https://webpack.github.io/
- WebPack with Gulp - https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html
- babel-loader - https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Comment: For clarification: Using this method you can avoid all the CommonJS-functional wrapping in the resulting javascript? It truly behaves like a simple concatenation?

Comment: Webpack will convert ES6 to CommonJS for you, as long as you have a .babelrc config file present with the es2015 preset. You don't have to do the wrapping yourself.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstanding: I don't have to do it, but it will happen. (good for clean namespaces, bad for someone who wants a straigforward concatenation, no wrappers).